# Why does my processing time drop when running the same function over and over again (with incremented values)?

Tags: java, macos

I was testing a new Method to replace my old one and made did some speed testing.
When I now look at the graph I see, that the time it takes per iteration drops drastically.[image]

Now I'm wondering why that might be.
My quess would be, that my graphics card takes over the heavy work, but the first function iterates n times and the second (the blue one) doesn't have a single iteration but "heavy" calculation work with doubles.

In case system details are needed:
OS: Mac OS X 10.10.4
Core: 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 (4x)
GPU: AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB

If you need the two functions:

New One:

```
private static int sumOfI(int i) {
    int factor;
    float factor_ = (i + 1) / 2;

    factor = (int) factor_;

    return (i % 2 == 0) ? i * factor + i / 2 : i * factor;
}
```

Old One:

```
private static int sumOfIOrdinary(int j) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

To clarify my question:
Why does the processing time drop that drastically?

Edit:
I understand at least a little bit about cost and such. I probably didn't explain my test method good enough. I have a simple for loop which in this test counted from 0 to 1000 and I fed each value to 1 method and recorded the time it took (for the whole loop to execute), then I did the same with the other method.

So after the loop reached about 500 the same method took significantly less time to execute.

Comment: To clarify, are the iterations how many times each function was called or the number inputted into the function?

Answer (score 2):

Java did not calculate anything on the graphic card (without help from other frameworks or classes). Also what you think is a "heavy" calculation is kinda easy for a cpu this day (even if division is kinda tricky). So speed depends on the bytecode generated and the Java optimisations when running a program and mostly on the Big-O Notation.

Your method `sumOfI` is just x statements to execute so this is O(1), regardless how large your i is its always only this x statements. But the `sumOfIOrdinary` uses one loop and its O(n) this will use y statements + i statements depending on the input.

So from the theory and in worst caste `sumOfI` is always faster as `sumOfIOrdinary`.
You can also see this problem in the bytecode view. `sumOfI` is only some `load` and `add` and `multiply` calls to the cpu. But for a loop the bytecode also uses a `goto` and needs to return to an older address and needs to execute lines again this will cost time.

On my VM with i=500000 the first method needs <1 millisecond and the second method because of the loop takes 2-4 millisecond.

Links to explain Big-O-Notation:

1. [Simple Big O Notation](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/simple-big-o-notation-post.html)
2. [A beginner's guide to Big O notation](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/)